# How do I upload an iOS APNs auth token to Firebase with the REST API or SDK?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to set up Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for iOS apps using the REST API or SDK?

The current (v1beta) API provides functionality to add apps to a project, and download the GoogleService-Info.plist file, but does not appear to provide any way to upload the APNs Auth token that is needed to enable FCM.

*Background:
I manage ~100 iOS apps which use Firebase Cloud Messaging. At the moment I need to manually upload the APNs Auth token for each app using the Firebase console. This needs to be done once when the app is set up, and routinely when the auth token expires. I'm looking for a way to automate this with a script, preferably an unattended CI, so that I don't need to do it manually.*

Comment: Yes there is an option to upload p12/pem files. Just follow these steps - Settings - Cloud Messaging - iOS App configuration - here you will get all the file options. APNs Authentication Key/APNs Certificates

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but it's not what I'm looking for. I need to upload the APNs key programatically using an API or SDK, and not use the console.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this @LukeVanIn?

Comment: @maxpower47 No. From Firebase support said this: "Currently, we do not support uploading APNs Auth key to Firebase using the Admin SDK or REST API. Firebase Cloud Messaging only uses Firebase Console to upload APNs Auth key."

Comment: @LukeVanIn do you have any updates regarding this ?

Comment: @AbdAl-rhmanTaherBadary No, sorry. This does not seem to be solved yet.

Comment: checking this in mid-2022 and still not available. Probably that would be help if we ask for this as a request? you may submit your requests to the Firebase team from here: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact

Comment: @LukeVanIn Any update on this one? How did you ended up solving your use case?

Comment: @f-so7 I ended up using Puppeteer (headless web browser) to automate the actions a human would perform. It took some upkeep and needed to be updated whenever the Firebase UI changed.